# Gradle exporting server configuration throwing error unsupported auth scheme: [Basic realm=public]

Tags: gradle, marklogic-10

I am trying to export server configuration using Gradle 8.1.1 but it is throwing error "unsupported auth scheme: [Basic realm=public]" , below is my gradle.properties.

mlAppName=8041-test

mlHost=localhost

mlUsername=admin

mlPassword=admin

mlRestPort=8041

mlAppServicesAuthentication=basic

Can anyone suggest please what is going wrong here.